# Terminal is exiting when i type mongodb command in the terminal

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB in my Linux mint computer and when I type mongod I get the following error,

```
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13188 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=umakanth-G3-3579
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-07-14T13:10:15.299+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

Can anyone  please help me solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use`

Seems that you already have a MongoDB server running on your machine, considering that you are using the default port (27017).

You can, for example, provide another port, then you will probably have 2 `mongod` instances running on your machine, or just see if the running daemon is useful to you.

**Edit**: It is possible that one instance of `mongod` already runs in your system. If this is just the native service in your local machine, you can find out by typing: `service mongodb status`. Then, in case the service is started, you can try to use it, for example by using the `mongo` shell. Simply type `mongo` (but note that it will use default username and password).

Comment: but I don't want 2 instances of MongoDB. can you suggest me steps so that I can use only one without that error

Comment: > or just see if the running daemon is useful to you

Comment: I am sorry to make this issue out of the picture, but I am new to the Linux operating system and I honestly don't know what you are referring to.

Comment: @UmakanthPendyala I updated my answer, see the **Edit** part.